# Xcode: Persistent Segmentation fault:11 when using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting mad with

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault:11

When I use Firebase in my project.

I read multiple question here about this Xcode bug, but it's terribly persisent when using Firebase.

I tried many solutions like cleaning the project, rebuilding, disabling bitcode, deleting derived data etc.

My code:

```
   @IBAction func saveBook(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {


    var arrayOfNames : [String] = [String]()
    for i in 0 ..< 6 {
        let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow:i, inSection:0)
        let cell : LongNameTableViewCell? = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! LongNameTableViewCell?
        if let item = cell?.textField.text {
            arrayOfNames.append(item)
        }
    }

   self.ref.child("books").childByAutoId().setValue(["title": arrayOfNames[0], "author": arrayOfNames[1], "pages_count":arrayOfNames[2]])
   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: It was weird when comparing with my situation, as the only solution I needed to do was clean my project folder, to get rid of this fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usually mentioned in similiar questions, this issue occurs when Xcode is for some reason unable to parse the code eq. variable types are ambiguous.

Although this is rather a workaround that a recommended fix, it worked for me:

```
self.ref.child("books").childByAutoId().setValue(["title":arrayOfNames[0] as! String, "author": arrayOfNames[1] as! String, "pages_count":arrayOfNames[2] as String!])
```

Obviously now Xcode shows warning that this kind of casting makes no sense, but fortunately this clears the error message.

**EDIT**

**Xcode 8 removed all these problems.**

Answer (score 0):

My way of solving this problem was do work backwards and comment out logic that could cause the issue.  There should have been a class file specified right below the error.  My issue was that I had a super class with this method:

```
func queryAssetsFromDB() -> [AssetDTO]? {
    return nil
}
```

and I was overriding it with

```
override func queryAssetsFromDB() -> [AssetDTO] {
    let cryptos = assetManager.findAllCrypto()
    return cryptos
}
```

notice the optional in the response array

Answer (score 0):

In your podfile you can try to uncomment use_frameworks!

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

Then run 'pod update' in the terminal. Restart your Xcode project.

This did it for me after struggling for two days with the Segmentation fault 11

Comment: I always use frameworks. For me, updating xcode to 8 solved the issue